# Open new window after click button

Tags: python, button, selenium, click

How to open a new window after click on a button?

I'm searching for something like that: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('description').click_new_window()`

I've tried to look at questions here on SO but nothing helped.

The point is that I want to click on a button which would open in new window because I want to save the old window with state so I can continue after look at new window.

EDIT:

HTML code of the button:

```
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="centerfloatelement nextbutton" ng-click="gotoReservation(xflight.hash + '-' + tripPair.realIndex, $parent.$index, $index, $event);"><span class="ng-binding">Ďalej</span><i class="icon right">&gt;</i></a>`
```

Do you have any advices?

Comment: Could you show the HTML code of the button you want to click? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I've edited the question and put the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering the web page you are working with, one and probably the easiest option would be to click the link, extract the desired data and go back:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('description').click()

# extract the data

driver.back()
```